# Firefox autofill only email

Tags: security, firefox, privacy

i'm totally new to this kind of practices so maybe i'm going to ask a stupid question, mostly because i couldn't find anything googling around.

I'm using Firefox 36 and i modified it so that it saves my passwords without asking me any time and this works.

But I have a problem with the autofill: I would like Firefox to autofill only the email field if it has a stored password, but that it does not autofill also the password field, so that it behaves like it doesn't have the password stored. 
This is because my computer is being used by other people from my house and i don't want them to access my website when i'm not around, but i also want to have my passwords stored in my browser so that i don't have to look here and there to find them if i forget them (and it happens often :P  ).

For now I just managed to totally avoid the autofill (setting to false the variable signon.autofillForms), but i want the email/usernames field suggested to me if i already used them.

Comment: Actually, I think I've misinterpreted your question. How do you propose that your browser fills in the password when you want it to and not when someone else does? Would a single master password that you have to enter to get the saved passwords be more to your liking?

Comment: yea maybe i didn't explain so well. I want the password to be saved in the password manager (together with username/email), but not to be suggested with the autofill, never, for nobody. Instead i want the email or username field to be autofilled if already stored. is it more clear?

Comment: Nope, remains as clear as mud to me. You want "the email or username field to be autofilled if already stored", isn`t this the very definition of an autofill suggestion? Do you not want it to appear in a drop-down as a possible option, but if someone successfully types the email then the password is filled in?

Comment: :) sorry for not being clear. Yea i want the autofill to work only for the username/email, but never for the password (pwd should not even be suggested in case someone types the right email).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to save your cleartext form fields (emails and the like) without saving passwords. Under `Preferences->Privacy->History` select **Remember History** (or **Use custom settings for history**, then check **Remember search and form history**), then under `Preferences->Security->Passwords` uncheck **Remember passwords for sites**.